# Filter from master list using array of objects in where clause linq C# query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a master list which contains objects of type A , refer the below screen shot

[image: master list]

Now I want to filter out the master list based on the values in array of object matching Ids in master list.

[image: array of objects]

Comment: What have you tried and what are you getting stuck on?

Comment: return masterSpecList.Where(x => x.ID.Contains(values.ToString())).ToList();

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: this what I tried using contains in linq from master to filter out but its values.ToString() returns objects not the string of values , may be that is causing error . I am not sure about that

Comment: It should be the other way around... `masterlist.Where(x => values.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Id).ToList()`. Select statement will get you just the IDs u want

Comment: yes, its working  , can you please post it as answer or do I need to update my question with more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
masterSpecList.Where(x => values.Contains(x.ID)).Select(x => x.ID).ToList().
```

Select statement will get you just the IDs u want. Contains should be the other way around like in the example above